# how to use mxml component in another actionscript

Tags: apache-flex, flex3, flex4, flexbuilder

how to use mxml component in another mxml component actionscript code

for ex.
in my main mxml file

```
private var warningMessage:Warning;//this is variable

if (!_controller.flashVars.chatSession || _controller.flashVars.chatSession == "")
            {

                warningMessage.includeInLayout = true;
                warningMessage.visible = true;
            }
            else
            {
                _controller.flashVars.showWarningMessage = "2";
            }
```

`private var warningMessage:Warning;`(warning is external custom component)

`warningMessage.visible=true` (and i want use it like this  in my actionscript code

but i am getting error saying "`Type was not found or was not compile time constant:warning`")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are three things that jump out.

1. If this component is in another SWC file, make sure to reference it in the project settings
2. Import the namespace or call it directly (com.whatever.namespace.Warning)
3. Make sure to call `new` to generate a new object.  In your code above, `warningMessage` is null.

`private var warningMessage:Warning = new Warning();`

Comment: +1. Also, "4. Don't write code in MXML Script section without function - it gets executed as if it was in class constructor, which is too early to manipulate controls - they're not created yet."

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have imported your custom component to the file you are using it.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to reference the other custom component as a mxml namespace.

Check the following article to get an accurate illustration:
http://www.roseindia.net/flex/custom-mxml-tags.shtml